# Cypress how to continue to call back end API until getting the expected result or timeout

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to create a test case which needs to call a "get" API method to get some information, but the back end server some time need time to process, so I need to create a loop to continue to call the "get" API method until getting the expected result or timeout.

the pseudo code looks like following

```
string responseMessage;    
for(i=0, i<10, i++) {
   responseMessage = callGetApi();
   if (responseMessage == "success") {
      exit loop;
   }else {
      wait 1 seccond;
   }
}
```

but I don't know how to create that kind of code in Cypress, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use async/await:

```
it('Test loop', async function() {
 for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
   await Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
     cy.request(your_url).should(response => {
       expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
       resolve();
     });
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one problem after I use your code in my test, the test is to continue running not stop even the response status is 200, and I added code  "console.log(i);" to show the iteration. the console show stop at second iteration.